# Docker containers out of same image don't work as expected

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a `docker-compose.yml` set up like this:

```
app:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile.dev
    image: test/test:${ENV}-test-app
    ...
```

`Dockerfile` called here has this line present:

```
...
RUN ln -s ../overrides/${ENV}/plugins ../plugins
...
```

And there is also a script I am running to get the whole environment up (it is dependant upon several containers so I tried to omit irrelevant info).

It is a bash script and running the following:

```
ENV=$1 docker-compose -p $1 up -d --force-recreate --build app
```

What I wanted to achieve is that i can run two app containers at the same time, and this works as follows:

```
sh initializer.sh foo -> creates foo-test-app container
sh initializer.sh bar -> creates bar-test-app container
```

Now the issue I'm having is that even when I have `--force-recreate` flag present two images created actually are seen as the same image with two different tags.

And what this does when I inspect the containers is that both containers have a symbolic link to:

```
overrides/foo/plugins
```

It doesn't notice when I create the new container to re-do that part. How can I fix it?

Also if I sh to one container and change the symbolic link, it is automatically changed in the other container as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to be in project flag when creating my containers. So this is what I did:

```
docker-compose -p foo up -d
docker-compose -p bar up -d
```

This would bring containers up as 2 separate projects.

[Link to documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/)

Answer (score 0):

$ENV in your dockerfile is not the same as the one in your compose file.

When you run `docker-compose up`, it can be roughly seen as a `docker build` followed by a `docker run`. So Docker builds the image, layer by layer, at that stage there is not env called ENV. Only at `docker run` will $ENV be used.

Environment variables at build stage can be used though, they are passed via `ARG`

```
// compose.yml
build:
  context: frontend
  args:
  - BUILD_ENV=${BUILD_ENV}

// dockerfile
ARG BUILD_ENV
RUN ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --$BUILD_ENV
```

You can do this to solve your problem however this will create one image per project, which you may not want. Or you can do it in an entrypoint script.

Comment: How does it initialize the first time if it is not the same `$ENV`?

Comment: I don't know, I guess you have it set in other script? Anyway, if you add a build ARG, it will invalidate the cache and create a new build which solves your problem